# Close Stage in JavaFx from task

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-2, task

**I am trying to close a Stage in JavaFX from a task (thread).**

In order to accomplish this, I tried to pass the references to the Stage to the a class that extends Task, setting the current Stage there.

Then closing the Stage when the call() is over. But **.close() and .hide() didn't hide/close the Stage** at all.

**Class: SampleStage**

```
public class SampleStage extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFx Dialog");
        final Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Click me to display popup dialog");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                Stage dialog = new Stage();
                Taskee task = new Taskee();
                dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
                task.setStage(dialog);
                new Thread(task).start();
                Scene scene2 = new Scene(new Group(new Text(25, 25, "Hello World!")));
                dialog.setScene(scene2);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Class Taskee:**

import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

```
public class Taskee extends Task<Void>{
    private Stage stage;
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            //@DoSomething()
            for(long l=0;l<10000;l++);
            System.out.println("i=" + i);
        }
        getStage().close();
        getStage().hide();
        return null;
    }
    public Stage getStage() {
        return stage;
    }
    public void setStage(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
    }
}
```

Note:  `getStage().getScene().getWindow().hide();` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`hide()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#hide--) method must be called on the FX Application thread. (In Java 8, your code would actually throw an exception.)

Use the `Task`'s `setOnSucceeded()` handler to close the stage in a situation like this:

```
public class Taskee extends Task<Void>{

    private Stage stage;

    public Taskee() {
        setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
                if (stage != null) {
                    stage.hide();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            //@DoSomething()
            for(long l=0;l<10000;l++);
            System.out.println("i=" + i);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public Stage getStage() {
        return stage;
    }
    public void setStage(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
    }
}
```